# If equals validate in handlebar template inside each loop

Tags: javascript, php, handlebars.js

I have a php array like this one

```
bookings[] = {"arrived","cancelled","departed"};
```

When display this array in handlebars template i want to check IF equal condition.

In the following example when value is equals to cancelled i want to display some text.

```
{{#each bookings}}
    {{#if this.value cancelled}}
        cancelled
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

This code is not working. What is alternative IF equals condition for handlebars to execute in loop.

Answer (score 3):

Now my code is working,

```
bookings = ["arrived", "cancelled", "departed"];
```

Handlebar function:

```
 Handlebars.registerHelper('check_status', function(val1, val2) {
    return val1 === val2;
 });
```

Handlebar template:

```
 {{#if (check_status this 'cancelled')}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you can't do an actual conditional in handlebars, you can only do `if true/false` which means that the `**value**` in `{{#if **value**}}` need to either be true or false

So what you will want to do is in the area of code where `this.value` is defined create a function like this

```
valueIsCancelled =  function(value) {
  return value === 'cancelled';
}
```

In your template you will do:

```
        {{#each bookings}}
         {{#if this.valueIsCancelled this.value}}
               cancelled
         {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
```

or another option is to define another variable where value is defined that would be a boolean

```
var isCancelled = value === 'cancelled';
```

and your template would look like this

```
        {{#each bookings}}
         {{#if this.isCancelled}}
               cancelled
         {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
```